# Not able to activate conda environment on Windows 8.1

Tags: conda

I am trying to activate conda but getting error

> Not a conda environment

This is my very first attempt in Machine learning. What I missed?

Trying to activate conda but getting message that not a conda environment

[image]

Available environments is listed here

[image]

Comment: [Please don't add errors as screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: What was the command you used for the environment creation?

Comment: conda activate <path>

Comment: That is the command for activation not for creation. Something like `conda create`

Comment: Did you try `source activate <path>` ?

Comment: @fgacon that is deprecated syntax

Comment: Path is typed incorrectly (should be `Projects` not `Project`).

Answer (score 0):

Path is typed incorrectly (should be Projects not Project).  Thank you merv pointing this out